# How to find when was table Last Truncated in Sybase? Any system table containing that Info

Tags: logging, sybase, system-tables

Hi All Sybase Experts And Coders,

I have a strange requirement to find out when my Tables in database was last truncated? Is there any way to find out using any of the systemtables in sybase.

If Answer to above is No, then any solution to implement this?
Since we have triggeres in DML statement level not sure will those come in handy in case of Truncate to log this execution time.

I'm using Sybase 15.7 version.

Any help is Highly Appreciated.

Cheers,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [database auditing](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/X85522.htm) in ASE.

Here is also an example of [querying the audit data](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01672.1570/html/sec_admin/X23329.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the info and links. However this would require higher privileges for me. Is there any way using system tables available in Sybase to deduce this information?

Comment: No there is no other way. You can also however configure replication with Replication Server and create some kind of handler for truncate on the target site. But this would be more sophisticated and complex approach.